# How can I replace the first occurrence of a specific character with a new character in a String?

Tags: java, methods

I'm writing a method whose signature is:

```
public static String changeFirst (String s, char oldChar, char newChar)
```

The method should return a string in which the leftmost occurrence of oldChar in s is replaced by newChar. If oldChar does not appear in s, the method should simply return s.Help?

Comment: What is stopping you from continuing/finishing your code?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the **work done so far** to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty solving it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: [`String#replaceFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) ... or `StringBuilder`...?

Comment: @Ian Incorrect. OP needs `indexOf` or a manual loop. My guess is a manual loop, for this homework assignment, otherwise just call `replaceFirst`.

Comment: @MadProgrammer true, but I would be careful with that in case we want to replace `*` with `$`. Anyway I suspect OP may not be allowed to use it (assuming it is homework about loops).

Comment: @Andreas I see, you are right. OP needs to replace it too.

Comment: @Pshemo So? Escape it? It's more the OP has done

Comment: @Pshemo That's why the Java gurus invented [`Pattern.quote()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) and [`Matcher.quoteReplacement()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: @Andreas MadProgrammer Yes, but judging by level of this question OP is still learning about Java/programming basics so introducing regex may not be best idea. But in real world sure, `replaceFirst` is perfect way to solve this problem.

Comment: @OP Hint: take a closer look at `String(char[])` constructor and `toCharArray` methods from String class.

Comment: @Pshemo Well, I don't know about the need for a loop, I have no evidence for of any limitations or requirments, if they are learning the API, then they should learn the API

Comment: look the OP is trying to (ab)use stackoverflow for homework (most likely coding bat). He simply has to get it to pass a series off simple tests... THe goal isn't to just give him the answer, but point him to some methods which he may use... Let him experiment with special cases...

Comment: @MadProgrammer There is no explicit limitation. It is just my hunch based on level of this question. Your approach is correct in real world and depending on purpose of this exercise you may be right, but IMO it looks more like basic loop exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StringBuilder` would be my first idea, as has already been demonstraed, a `char` array might be an idea, but `String` already has this functionality built in [`String#replaceFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), for example

```
public static String changeFirst(String in, char old, char with) {
    String oldValue = Pattern.quote(Character.toString(old));
    String withValue = Matcher.quoteReplacement(Character.toString(with));
    return in.replaceFirst(oldValue, withValue);
}
```

Then you could use it something like...

```
String replaced = changeFirst("Banana's with Pajamas", 'P', 'K');
System.out.println(replaced);
replaced = changeFirst("Apples", 'P', 'K');
System.out.println(replaced);
replaced = changeFirst("What's with the *uck", '*', 't');
System.out.println(replaced);
```

Which outputs something like...

```
Banana's with Kajamas
Apples
What's with the tuck
```

Comment: `withValue` also requires escaping since `$x` is reference to match from group `x` which allows us to do things like `"foo".replaceFirst(".","$0$0")` which returns `ffoo`. Anyway we don't need to reinvent escaping code, we can simply use `String oldValue = Pattern.quote(Character.toString(old));` and `String withValue = Matcher.quoteReplacement(Character.toString(with));`

Comment: Know there was an API for it, have a 3 year old trying to play Lego Star Wars on my other PC, but I'll get around to updating it eventually

Answer (score 1):

You should show us what you have done unto this point however I am providing a hint here. Note since it is homework I will Not just give you the answer

```
    public  static String changeFirst(String s, char oldChar, char newChar){
    //now how to implement it 
    //play around with methods like this
    s.indexOf(oldChar);//this gets you the leftmost occurence
    //and 
    //string+char or string+ string or char+char creates a sttring
    //and try "someString".substring(a,b);// creates a substring from a inclusive to //be exclusive (0 is the first       character.) so "foo".substring(0,2).equals("fo") //f is the 0th character o is the first and the second oh is the     2th character //but isnt counted
    //next time put some effort into the questions you ask here let us know all the information and the issues you had
    }
```